# Value-initializing std::array member?

Tags: c++, c++20

Let's suppose I have a class template that has a `std::array` member:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
public:
    C();

private:
    std::array<T, 42> a;
};
```

How do I define `C::C` such that `a` will always be value-initialized (not default-initialized)?  ie such that the constructor calls `T()` to initialize every element of `a` - and that, for example, if `T` is `int`, then every element of `a` is guaranteed to be zero and not an indeterminant value?

```
int main() {
   C<int> c;
   assert(c.a[13] == 0); // ignoring private for exposition
}
```

**UPDATE**

Additional information for posterity:

1. `std::array` is an aggregate type with a single element `T[N]`
2. Initialization of `std::array` by an init-list is aggregate initialization
3. Aggregate initialization with an empty init-list causes each element to not be explicitly initialized.  Such elements are initialized as if by copy-initialization from an empty init-list.
4. The array `T[N]` is therefore copy-initialized from an empty init-list.  It is also an aggregate therefore 2 and 3 apply recursively.
5. Each of the N elements of `T[N]` are copy-initialized from an empty init-list.
6. Each T object is copy-list-initialized with an empty init-list as per `[dcl.init.list]/3`.  The final clause of that chain is reached which reads:

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

and voila.  Initializing `std::array` with an empty init list `{}` causes its elements to be value-initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use inline member initialization:

```
private:
    std::array<T, 42> a{};
```

If you absolutely want to do it with a constructor instead (why though?) then:

```
C()
    : a{}
{ }
```

Comment: How does that look in a definition of `C::C` ?  (ie the question asks for a definition of `C::C`)

Comment: @AndrewTomazos what do you mean? You don't need anything special in the constructor definition.

Comment: The question asks for a definition of `C::C` - ie an answer should start with `C::C() /*...*/`, not using a default member initializer.

Comment: ie Does `C::C() : a{} {}` do the same thing and would it also work?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos The question does not ask to not use an in-place member initializer. So the definition of `C::C` could be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: You might want to do it from a constructor, because you might have a second constructor (say `C::C(X,Y,Z)`) that assigns values to `a` in its body, therefore does not want to unnecessarily pay for value-initialization.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Inline initialization is skipped when calling a ctor that initializes it. So you don't pay anything.

Comment: @NikosC.: I said assigns values to a, not initializes a.  ie `C::C(X,Y,Z) { for (auto& x : a) x = ???; }`.  In such a case you would pay unnecessarily for value-initialization of `a`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos this can be solved as well, like with `C() : a{func_returning_array()} {}`